# How to generate a large dataframe more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I need to generate a large dataframe that I will then use to train a neural network, however I am a novice at this and I suspect my solution is very inefficient. Each row of the dataframe should be a complete graph with a fixed amount of vertices and random edge weights between 0 and 1. Each column should correspond to an edge, with one final column corresponding to the minimum spanning tree value. The entries in the dataframe should then be the edge weights and in the final column the MST values of all of these graphs. I have been able to write a code that does just this however it generates these dataframes extremely slowly. My goal was to have 100000+ rows, if not more, for better training, however generating these takes ages and at times even failed when I tried to generate a million rows, my computer couldn't handle that request. My question is if something specific I am using is slowing me down/wrong and what I could do instead to speed this up and make it more efficient? Or is it not possible to speed things up? Any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have been using so far. Like I said, I am a novice at all of this so there might be mistakes. I know that things like appending dataframes are not great for computation times but I am not sure how else I could get the desired result. What could I do better to generate the dataframe more efficiently?

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import random

#Function that generates a complete graph on n vertices with random edge weights between the values "lowBound" and "upBuond"
def complete_weighted_graph(nNodes, lowBound, upBound):
    graph = nx.complete_graph(nNodes, create_using=None) 
    for i in range(nNodes):
        for j in range(i+1, nNodes): 
            graph.add_edge(i, j, weight=random.uniform(lowBound, upBound)) 
    return graph 


#Function that transforms a graph into a dataframe which we can use to train the NN. We get a single row corresponding to the graph, and each column corresponds to an edge. The entries are the edge weights
def graph_to_df(G): 
    edge_weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight') 
    edge_weights_dict = {(u,v):w for (u,v),w in edge_weights.items()} 
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=edge_weights_dict.keys()) 
    df.loc[0] = edge_weights_dict.values()
    return df

#This function generates the dataframe which we will later use to train the NN. The input nNodes is the number of vertices in the graphs. It generates a dataframe with nRows many rows corresponding to nRows many example graphs with random edge weights. The last column contains the MST values of the graph
def generate_df(nNodes, nRows, lowBound, upBound):                       
    frames = []
    for i in range(nRows): 
        K = complete_weighted_graph(nNodes, lowBound, upBound) 
        df=graph_to_df(K) 
        df['MST'] = [nx.minimum_spanning_tree(K).size(weight="weight")] 
        frames.append(df) 
    return pd.concat(frames) 

#Here I tried generating a dataframe with 1000000 rows but that was too much for my computer
df = generate_df(nNodes=50, nRows=1000000, lowBound=0, upBound=1)
```

Thank you